# How to add a new custom PHP starting tag to TextMate App?

Tags: php, wordpress, macos, tags, textmate

Is it possible to add a new custom starting tag to recognize PHP code in TextMate on Mac?

i.e.  I need to use

```
[insert_php]

echo "Hello World"

[/insert_php]
```

Instead of the default code

```
<?php

echo "Hello World"

?>
```

I need that because I'm using a WordPress plugin which allows me to insert a custom php code **[insert_php] code ... [/insert_php]** into posts and pages but it's a bit complected code so I'm using TextMate to write it externally and then will paste it in a WP page .. so the standard PHP styling in TextMate will make my job easier.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the grammar definitions for every language. In your case:

- Open the Bundle editor
- Search for PHP -> Language Grammars -> PHP
- Find the block containing `name = 'meta.embedded.block.php';`, highlighted in this screenshot:

[image]

- Duplicate it by pressing CTRL+Shift+D
- Inside the new block, change `begin` to `'\[insert_php\]'`
- Change `end` to `'\[/insert_php\]'`, the result should look like in the second screenshot:

[image]

Now your custom begin/end tag should work.

Comment: I was a bit confused because I was using the old version but after I updated to TextMate 2.0 your method worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Write your code with `<? and ?>` then when you're done, replace it with your custom tags. Boom.

Comment: Pawd,

This is what I'm doing at the moment but it's a pain to do that every time, because I'm doing a lot of custom coding and working with someone who want's to see different results every 5 seconds ... and I have different codes in different pages/posts so cutting this extra step (find and replace) will be really helpful.